# How to Disable the Hardware-Based Backlight Key on a Keychron K2 via macOS?

Tags: keyboard, settings, karabiner

I'm using a Keychron K2 keyboard with my Mac, and I'm struggling to disable the backlight key that changes the keyboard's lighting. This key seems to be managed at a hardware level because its keypresses do not register in Karabiner-Elements' EventViewer.

I attempted to create a custom rule in Karabiner-Elements to disable it, but without the key code, I couldn't proceed:

```json
{
  "description": "Disable backlight key",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "YOUR_KEY_CODE_HERE",
        "modifiers": {
          "optional": ["any"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's becoming a nuisance as I often accidentally press it, causing unwanted changes to the lighting. I've checked the manual ([Keychron K2 Manual PDF](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0059/0630/1017/files/k2_user_manual_english_version.pdf?v=1609223925)), but it doesn't provide a solution to lock the backlight setting.

Has anyone successfully disabled this key, or is there a known method to lock the backlight settings on a Keychron K2?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the keyboard **does** provide a code to lock the backlight.

> fn+ L + Light Effect Key (long press for 3s)  Lock / Unlock the Backlight Effect

Check the [key combinations table of Keychron K2](https://www.keychron.com/blogs/news/k2-key-combinations).